# How to update an xml file in project folder

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to add data in to an existing xml file.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddData("123Texttbox value");
    }

    public static void AddData(string message)
    {
        string file = Properties.Settings.Default.XMLFileFullName;

        var doc = XDocument.Load(file);

        doc.Root.Add(
                new XElement("Request",
                new XElement("ID", message.Substring(0, 3)),
                new XElement("Message", message))
            );


        Properties.Settings.Default.XMLFileFullName = doc.ToString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

setting.setting

```
    <userSettings>
    <Test.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="XMLFileFullName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>@"Request\request.xml"</value>
        </setting>
    </Test.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

Actual xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <requests>

    </requests>
```

Expected xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <requests> 
           <request>123</request>
           <request> 
              <request>123Texttbox value</request>
           </request>
        </requests>
```

But this is not giving me the expected xml output. Did I miss anything? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct saving code follows:

```
public static void AddData(string message)
{
    string file = Properties.Settings.Default.XMLFileFullName;

    var doc = XDocument.Load(file);

    doc.Root.Add(
        new XElement("Request",
        new XElement("ID", message.Substring(0, 3)),
        new XElement("Message", message))
    );

    doc.Save(file);
}
```

Your code tries to update the setting 'XMLFileFullName' with the string representation of the XML file.

Comment: this throws "Illegal characters in path." exception

Comment: First check out your setting file to see the XMLFileFullName is actually a valid file name, you may need to map file name.

Comment: setting.setting has Name = XMLFileFullName and Value =@"Request\request.xml"

Comment: Try to use an absolute path and file name like: "c:\file.xml"